# Sencha Touch 2.3 with Cordova 3.5 launch time is long

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.3

If you create a sample Sencha Touch 2.3 app using sencha app generate... and package it with Cordova, you will see that it takes about 4 seconds to launch the app and show the main view. If this basic skeleton app takes this long, then actual apps that have many more views, controllers, stores etc will take much longer (6-8+ seconds).

Is there any way to speed up the launch? For reference, lets take the example of the sencha started app itself. It takes 4 seconds now. So how do we improve the performance so that it takes 1 or less than 1 second to launch?

Answer (score 1):

Aside that you shoud only include the necessary controllers, views etc... there is a great difference in time from generate a development, testing build than a production build that compresses, minimizes all js (Sencha+your code) in a unique 'js' file and a unique 'css' file that improves greatly the startup time (in development phase each class is a separate file).

```
sencha app build production
```

Comment: I do a sencha app build package as i have to then package the app with Cordova for android and iOS. Is production build recommended over package build in this case?

Comment: Package is the best solution, also minimizes content for static content inside a device.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be:

- Avoid overnesting views
- Do hierarchical loading (not all views controller models and stores in app.js but use requires)
- Be sure you are not creating objects and let them around without proper destruction.
- The speed depends a lot on phones so if your target are limited resource phones might wanna consider other options.

That been said this is not native and you wont get the same speed (at least not right now) but you get a lot of other benefits.

Comment: I have about 20views, 5 controllers, 10 models and 10 stores, all defined in app.js. Should i define just 1 view and 1 controller in app.js and mention the remaining views, controllers, models and stores as requires in the controller?

Comment: nope, require should be used in a way that each view require all other views it will use. E.g in app.js can laod MainView.js and lets say that view has 2 items (MyPanel, and MyGrid) those 2 views would be good to have as a require of MainView.js

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time launching of app takes long time because of the below reasons(which i faced)

1.Unnecessary loading of controllers,views in app.js directly.

2.Unnecessary loading of static images/pdf(any static content) every time whenever we refresh the app.

Below steps would be useful,if you follow these properly,in any sencha touch app.

1. Do not load all controllers inside app.js directly,you can do loading of controllers device specific
   using profile,like below

   profiles: ['Tablet', 'Phone'],

   Above line would be in app.js,which is responsible for loading of corresponding profile,these profile files are further responsible for loading of all the controllers and views as per the device.
2. app.json file contains app.cache section,inside this there is cache section where you can mention all the static images or pdf,to avoid unnecessary loading every time.

Comment: As i am packaging my app with Cordova for android and iOS, does the app.cache logic make sense here? I understand it would cache the images in the case of a web app that has to repeatedly download the image every time. But what about a packaged app, does the cache logic work here too?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [malcubierre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748337/malcubierre), we need to compress all the required js and css files using `sencha app build` command. If you are targetting for mobile phones especially then you can go for `sencha app build package` command. 
You can also remove the extra imports from **app.scss** file which you are not using in the application. Removing extra imports in theming part reduces the loading time of **app.css**.